# How to use ON CONFLICT with a primary key on a foreign table

Tags: postgresql

I am basically trying to replicate data from a table on one server to another.

I have two identical databases on the servers. I created a foreign table called opentickets_aux1 to represent the opentickets table on the secondary server on the primary server. Both have a primary key of incidentnumber. I can access the data in the foreign table just fine but when I try the following SQL,I get "ERROR:  there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification."

```
INSERT INTO opentickets_aux1 (SELECT * FROM opentickets)
ON CONFLICT (incidentnumber)
DO
 UPDATE SET 
 status = EXCLUDED.status,
 lastmodifieddate = EXCLUDED.lastmodifieddate
```

I want to update a few columns if the primary key exist. I use this statement for other queries and they work when its a local table. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

A foreign table cannot have a primary key constraint, because PostgreSQL wouldn't be able to enforce its integrity. Therefore, you cannot use `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` with foreign tables.

Your idea also does not handle rows that are deleted on the foreign server, but maybe that's intentional.

If you want a local copy of a foreign table, the easiest way would be to create a materialized view on the foreign table.

If that is not your desire (perhaps because you don't want to copy deletions), you'd have to use statements like

```
INSERT INTO localtable
SELECT * FROM foreigntable f
WHERE NOT EXISTS
         (SELECT 1 FROM localtable l
          WHERE f.id = l.id);

UPDATE localtable l
SET /* all columns from f */
FROM foreigntable f
WHERE f.id = l.id
  AND (f.*) <> (l.*);
```